# Group Policy not applying to XP machines 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, group-policy

Here's a quick rundown of the issue we're seeing here.  And its a very blanketed question for the moment because Im not getting much in the way of error messages.

Trying to deploy different group policies throughout our organization here. For the moment, we're really just wanting to use it for printer deployment per machine since we have so many users moving around.
We do all of this through GP Management.  Right click on the OU and "Create and Link a GPO Here..."
On the Windows 7 machines, we have no issues, it just works.  But the second we try to deploy one for an OU with XP machines, we get absolutely no response at all.  We an do a gpupdate /force and gpresult and see that the GPO was applied, but it doesnt reflect any changes at all.  Dont get any errors at all.  We just dont see any of the settings in the GPO reflected.  Weve done testing with different settings and Ive moved my Win7 machine to many different groups testing the GPO on it.  It applies with no issue.

Part of the problem is that we came in after another IT group and had to reverse engineer many things here.  So I dont know what theyve done to the servers here to cause an issue like this, or if its even something they've done.  Could just be my own ignorance.

But we would like to find out whats causing the hangup here.  Id like to move beyond just using it to deploy printers.

I know its not a ton to go off of, but if someone can just point me in the right direction itd help.  If any more info is needed, just let me know.  Im having to be quick so I apoligize if its a bit jumbled.

Thanks

Comment: How are you deploying the printers in GPO? I can think of at least 4 different ways to.

Answer (score 2):

Are you deploying the printers using Group Policy Preferences? If so, you need to install the Windows XP client side extensions.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3628

Comment: I thought about that too but figured since he put 2003 server he wasn't.  Good call.

Comment: You know what, Christopher? I didn't even see the W2K3 tag. I'm notoriously bad at looking at the tags. Good catch... Stoopid tags...

Comment: You can use GPP with Server 2003 if you are running the GPMC on a Vista or 7 workstation, so there's a good chance that he might be using GPP anyway, which is why I left my comment on the OP.

Comment: Im deploying the printers within the GPO under Computer Configuration - Deployed Printers.

Comment: Where exactly is that in the GPO? I don't see Deployed Printers in W2K3 or W2K8.

Comment: Oh, you're looking at Deployed Printers in the Print Management MMC console, right? Have you deployed the PushPrinterConnections.exe utility to the Windows XP clients via a startup script or logon script? If not, you need to.